# Tabulator plugin not loading

Tags: jquery, html, tabulator

I am working off the basic example for the Tabulator plugin [here](http://tabulator.info/quickstart/3.5#basic-example).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Storage &amp; Spares</title>

  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />

  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/3.5.3/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/3.5.3/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

  
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  var json = (function() {
   var json = null;
   $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conormc93/db/master/db.json",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
     json = data;
    }
   });
   return json;
  })();

  $("#table_id").tabulator({
   height:205,
   layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
   columns:[ //Define Table Columns
    {title:"Picture", field:"Picture", width:150},
    {title:"Pins", field:"Pins"},
    {title:"Size", field:"Size"},
    {title:"Supplier", field:"Supplier"},
    {title:"Order Code", field:"Order Code"},
    {title:"Manufacturer", field:"Manufacturer"},
    {title:"Part Number", field:"Part Number"},
    {title:"Description", field:"Description"},
    {title:"Link", field:"Link"},
    {title:"Location", field:"Location"},
    {title:"Catagory", field:"Catagory"},
   ],
   rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
   },
  });
  
  $("#table_id").tabulator("setData", json);
 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container">
     <div id="logo">
      <img alt="logo" src= "C:/Users/cmcgrat1/Website/images/logo.png">
     </div>
     <div id="menu">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="C:/Users/cmcgrat1/Website/index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="C:/Users/cmcgrat1/Website/spares.html" accesskey="2" title="">Spares</a></li>
       <li class="current_page_item"><a href="C:/Users/cmcgrat1/Website/storage.html" accesskey="3" title="">Storage</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">Links</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">Sitemap</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  
  <div id="table_id"></div>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="addItemForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    
     <div class="modal-header text-center">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Add Spare Item Form</h4>
     </div>
     
     <div class="modal-body mx-2">
     
      <form action="test.php" method="POST">
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Pins/Length</label>
         <input type="number" name="pins_length" class="form-control" min=0 placeholder=" ">
         
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Size</label>
         <input type="text" name="size" class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Supplier</label>
         <input type="text" name="supplier" class="form-control" list="suppliers_list" />
         <datalist id="suppliers_list">
          <option selected>Farnell</option>
          <option>RS</option>
          <option>Phoenix Contact</option>
          <option>Radionics</option>
          <option>Vision ID</option>
          <option>Connector Solutions Ltd.</option>
          <option>ITM/LCOM</option>
          <option>PC Engines/MS Distribution</option>
          <option>Valeo</option>
         </datalist>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Order Code</label>
         <input type="number" name="order_code" class="form-control" min=0 placeholder=" ">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Manufacturer</label>
         <input type="text" name="manufacturer" class="form-control" list="manufacturers_list" />
         <datalist id="manufacturers_list">
          <option>....</option>
          <option>....</option>
          <option>....</option>
          <option>....</option>
         </datalist>
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Part Number</label>
         <input type="text" name="part_number" class="form-control" id="inputCity"></br>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <label>Location</label></br>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label>Section</label>
         <select id="section" name="section" class="form-control">
          <option selected>A</option>
          <option>B</option>
          <option>C</option>
          <option>D</option>
          <option>E</option>
          <option>F</option>
          <option>G</option>
          <option>H</option>
          <option>I</option>
          <option>J</option>
          <option>K</option>
          <option>L</option>
         </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label>Row</label>
         <select id="row" name="row" class="form-control">
          <option selected>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
          <option>8</option>
          <option>9</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
         </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label>Column</label>
         <select id="column" name="column" class="form-control">
          <option selected>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
         </select></br>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label>Link</label>
         <input type="url" class="form-control" name="form_url" placeholder="https://www.example.com">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Picture</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" name="picture" placeholder=" ">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label>Catagory</label>
         <select id="catagory" name="catagory" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Connectors &amp; Accessories</option>
          <option>Logic &amp; Resistors</option>
          <option>Nuts &amp; Bolts</option>
          <option>Tools</option>
          <option>Consumables</option>
          <option>Cable Assemblies</option>
          <option>Test Equipment</option>
          <option>Run In</option>
          <option>Spares</option>
          <option>Benetel</option>
         </select>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label>Description</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
       
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
   <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addItemForm">Add Spare Item Form</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="copyright" class="container">
   <p>&copy; Valeo. All rights reserved. | Design by <a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Conor McGrath</a>.</p>
  </div>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

I get the errors `t.widget is not a function` and `$(...).tabulator is not a function`.

From my understanding, this is usually a problem with the order that the script files are written. I have tried re-arranging the script tags also.

My question is, is there an error in the way I have tried to initialise the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The issue there was that you had only included the jQuery source, you also needed to include the jQuery-Ui source in your project as well.

The good news is that Tabulator 4.0 is out now and it is no longer dependent on jQuery so you can use it straight out the box

[Checkout The Tabulator Website For Info](http://tabulator.info)

I hope that helps